# jQuery event for delegate other than click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the css of a group of div blocks on load. The following code is working just fine. However, the change is only made when the user click on the div. How can I trigger the change automatically without requiring the user intervention? In other words, which events should I use to accomplish my goal.

```
$("body").delegate(".shortTopicInfoHolder", "click", function()
{
       $(".shortTopicInfoHolder").toggleClass("shortTopicInfoHolderRTL");
});
```

I am trying to use delegate to make sure that the change remains. Have tried to directly toggle the class when document is ready but it did not work for div blocks that were created after the change was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing it on page load why not use `$(document).ready()`? It is called on completion of the DOM load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".shortTopicInfoHolder").toggleClass("shortTopicInfoHolderRTL");
});
```

Comment: It does snot guarantee future changes. I have to use either delegate or live

Comment: you would still use the same ready call back to initially toggle the class, but use the delegate function as well to ensure that all other divs with the class bind to the toggleClass callback...however, you'll have to do some extra work to make sure that the new divs that get added are in the same state as the existing divs

Answer (score 0):

Like Emmanuel mentioned, you can just you use the [ready callback](http://jsfiddle.net/nadirabid/x6Dc2/) or if you're looking for a timed event then you can use:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(".shortTopicInfoHolder").toggleClass("shortTopicInfoHolderRTL");
        $("body").delegate(".shortTopicInfoHolder", "click", function() {
            $(".shortTopicInfoHolder").toggleClass("shortTopicInfoHolderRTL");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other answers the on ready code will get the initial load set properly.

If there will be more loads coming in the future, you will probably need to modify your callback functions to trigger the class toggles.

There is not a DOM changed event.

Comment: There are `DOMActivate`,`DOMFocusIn`,`DOMFocusOut`,`DOMAttrModified`,`DOMCharacterDataModified`,`DOMNodeInserted`,`DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`,`DOMNodeRemoved`,`DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument`,`DOMSubtreeModified`,`DOMContentLoaded` but not if you need IE

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the click event right after the delegation

```
$("body").delegate(".shortTopicInfoHolder", "click", function()
{
       $(".shortTopicInfoHolder").toggleClass("shortTopicInfoHolderRTL");
});
$('.shortTopicInfoHolder').trigger('click');
```